# Error adding push notifications to my rails 3 app using Rpush

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I added the rpush gem to my gemfile and ran bundle install. The next step according to the documentation is to run rpush init. This gave me the following error.

`You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your init environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/init.rb
/Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:inresolve_string_connection'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in spec'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:inestablish_connection'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:ininstance_eval'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in execute_hook'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:inblock in on_load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in each'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:inon_load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:ininstance_exec'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:inblock in run_initializers'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in each'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:inrun_initializers'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in initialize!'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:inmethod_missing'
    from config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:inload'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in block in load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:inload_dependency'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rpush-1.0.0/bin/rpush:31:in'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rpush:23:in load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rpush:23:in'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in'`

I then added an init.rb file into my environment folder that followed what the error suggested. Here is what I added to init.rb

```
CityRails::Application.configure do
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
end
```

I then ran rpush init again and I'm getting the following error

`/Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:inresolve_string_connection'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in spec'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:inestablish_connection'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:ininstance_eval'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in execute_hook'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:inblock in on_load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in each'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:inon_load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:ininstance_exec'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:inblock in run_initializers'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in each'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:inrun_initializers'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in initialize!'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:inmethod_missing'
    from config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:inload'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in block in load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:inload_dependency'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rpush-1.0.0/bin/rpush:31:in'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rpush:23:in load'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rpush:23:in'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
    from /Users/mcarthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in'`

Please help. I've been working on this for 3 days. You guys are great.

Edit: I am using sqlite3 for test/dev environments and pg for production.

This is what my database.yml looks like:

`development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000`

`test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000`

`production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: cityrails_production
  pool: 5`

Output from local rake db:migrate -

`database: /Users/mcarthur/Desktop/apps/city-rails/db/development.sqlite3`

### Status   Migration ID    Migration Name

up     20140423191412  Create users
   up     20140423191450  Create contacts
   up     20140423191657  Create venues
   up     20140423191730  Create cities
   up     20140423194439  Create friendships
   up     20140423212732  Create invitations
   up     20140423212915  Add default to invitations status
   up     20140423213804  Create kptwilios
   up     20140423221018  Create push notifications
   up     20140423221315  Create device tokens
   up     20140423221356  Add default to device token environment
   up     20140423225205  Create delayed jobs
   up     20140430001800  Add user id to venues
   up     20140430001824  Add json info to venues
   up     20140616234552  Add api id to venues
   up     20140617012705  Add user id override to venues
   up     20140617024603  Add incognito to users
   up     20150107184219  Block users

Output from heroku run rake db:migrate -

`database: dfvpbkpnbntg2f`

### Status   Migration ID    Migration Name

up     20140423191412  Create users
   up     20140423191450  Create contacts
   up     20140423191657  Create venues
   up     20140423191730  Create cities
   up     20140423194439  Create friendships
   up     20140423212732  Create invitations
   up     20140423212915  Add default to invitations status
   up     20140423213804  Create kptwilios
   up     20140423221018  Create push notifications
   up     20140423221315  Create device tokens
   up     20140423221356  Add default to device token environment
   up     20140423225205  Create delayed jobs
   up     20140430001800  Add user id to venues
   up     20140430001824  Add json info to venues
   up     20140616234552  Add api id to venues
   up     20140617012705  Add user id override to venues
   up     20140617024603  Add incognito to users
   up     20150107184219  Block users

I tried changing my database.yml file from cityrails_production to dfvpbkpnbntg2f and it did not work.

Comment: what's your database?  That's where it's blowing up

Comment: sqlite3 in dev/test and pg in production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see rpush-1.0.0 in your stacktrace. 1.0.0 is very old. Please use 2.2.0

Comment: Incredible. That is exactly what was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`database configuration does not specify adapter` indicates that the `config/database.yml` file has not been set up correctly. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database for details about what should be in that file.

Specifically, the error message is pointing to not finding `adapter: <database type>`

https://gist.github.com/erichurst/961978 has some examples of `database.yml` that you could refer to while setting up one.

Comment: I have edited my question with the database.yml file.

Comment: Whats the output on running `rake db:migrate:status`?

Comment: I see you have included the output in the question now. Weird. `rake db:migrate:status` is able to use the database config correctly. Are you still getting an error when you run `rpush init`?

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting the same database configuration does not specify adapter message.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment :-)